# how to add @unique validation while updating content in laravel Lighthouse?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

I have Laravel 8 with Lighthouse package for Graph QL,

I have added @unique directive for "name" attribute, but I am unable to apply this while updating any record, as I want to skip the currently updating record for checking unique,

Below is schema for update

updateRole(id: ID, name: String! @trim @rules(apply : ["unique:roles,name"]), isActive: Int!): Role! @update

When I manually added "id" with rule, it works fine, but I don't know how to make it dynamic rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the ID you are receiving from the database to update the data with your Validation rule something like that.

```
public function update(Request $request, Model $ModelVarible)
{
    $request->validate(["name"=> "unique:tablename,fieldname,{$ModelVarible->id},id"]);
    return redirect('route name');
}
```

Comment: this is laravel syntex and function, I want to wright in GraphQL scheme

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you finally found a solution ?

Comment: Finally solved this with a custom validator : https://lighthouse-php.com/5/security/validation.html#validator-classes